# How do I remove any SELinux context or ACL?

Tags: acl, selinux

HI, I have some files, that I'd like to remove the SELinux context or ACLs from (denoted by a '`.`' or a '`+`' respectively when using `ls -alZ`).

I don't have too much time on my hands to read on the , etc on how to use `chcon` etc., so I just want to quickly know how to disable them all.

Also, if someone knows a SELinux/ACL Cheat-Sheet, that would be terrific.

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Notice the dots right after the permission symbols: `drwxr-xr-x.`, etc.

Comment: What is this ' . ' and ' + ' you are talking about? I don't see anything like that on the -Z specific output of ls.

Comment: maybe you don't use Ext4? I'll post an edit shortly, since this isn't getting any replies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`setfacl -b` will remove the ACL on a file. `setfattr -x security.selinux` will remove the SELinux file context, but you will probably have to boot with SELinux completely disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You never stated what you are removing ACL's "from", but if it is a file system, unmounting it and remounting it without the ACL option will do the job quickly.

Comment: I can't remount my root partition just to remove ACL's, I just want to remove them once from a directory.

Comment: More details like this in the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As long as selinux is in permissive or enforcing you will not be able to remove the .
This indicates selinux attributes are set. Since Permissive is still doing the selinux checks (just not enforcing) it will force the . on the end of attributes.

To fully remove the dot the only way I know of is to completely stop selinux.

vim /etc/selinux/config and set to disabled. 
Reboot
then run this command on the files you want to remove the . (selinux acl)

```
setfattr -x security.selinux myfilewithdot
```

Here is the output from my desktop Centos7 after setting selinux to

setfattr -x security.selinux /foo.txt

Comment: I took too long and didn't see Ignacios post above.